# Parse JSON with field name containing underscore

Tags: json, go

So I have JSON like this

```
{"Name":"Jame","Age":6,"Original_Name":"Jameson"}
```

In order to get "Name" and "Age" in Go, I just need to use a corresponding struct

```
type Result struct {
  Name string
  Age int
}
```

But how do I get the field "Original_Name" since I cannot use underscore in go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this work:

```
type Result struct {
  Name string
  Age int
  Originalname string `json:"Original_Name"`
}
```

Comment: @JSNoob Notice they're backticks, not single quotes. ' is different from \`

Comment: OMG I'd never notice that difference. Really saved my day : )